# How can I set a new value for field form depending what user selects in choice field? Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I have a form with 3 fields, "productoOc" which is a related field, "cantidad" and "precioCompra", I need to set value for "precioCompra" when user selects a "productoOc". This value comes from a thrid entity which have prices.

My code:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('ordenCompra')
        ->add('productoOc', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'NivalInventarioBundle:InProducto',
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                    ->orderBy('u.nombre', 'ASC');
            },
            'choice_label' => function ($displayname) {
                                return $displayname->getDisplayName();},
            'by_reference' => true,
            'expanded' => false,
            'placeholder' => 'Seleccione una opción',
            'mapped' => true,
            'multiple' => false,
        ))
        ->add('cantidad')
        ->add('precioCompra')
    ;
}
```

Comment: If you need to change formfields on the moment that a user presses a button, edit a form-field or select an other option from the select you will need to use javascript with or without an AJAX request to get the required data.

Comment: Where can I find an example?

Comment: I have been trying for a while, to use Ajax to do my stuff but Im not able yet to do it, somebody can help me?